# axios post requests - Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm using axios inside a cli node script. I've noticed that sometimes inside the console this error will be logged:

```js
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.foobar.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:67:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
```

It will be handled by the `.catch()` function and the next axios request to the same address will continue work and I get 200 status code. Is there any reason that cause that a `axios.post` request can generate that error?

Comment: Try adding http:// before your url

Comment: I am facing the same error, Can you please post your code so that it helps others?

Answer (score 2):

As @Javapocalypse commented, you should add `http://` beginning of your url.

Comment: The url I pass to the axios configuration already have the `http` sheme, I think the problem was with the amount of requests send to the server at the same time. Anyway thank you for the help :)

Comment: how did you solve this? I have to send many requests at the same time using promise.all